# Returning "null" value from Javascript "filter" function

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say i have the following array: `arr = [1, 2, 0, null, 4]`, and i want to filter all the "0" in the array.
An example code would be:

```
arr.filter((val) => {return val !== 0})
//>> [1, 2, null, 4]
```

It works just fine. But if i use an if statement instead, the "null" value isn't returned:

```
arr.filter((val) => {if(val !== 0) return val})
//>> [1, 2, 4]
```

It only works if i return an array containing the "value":

```
arr.filter((val) => {if(val !== 0) return [val]})
//>> [1, 2, null, 4]
```

Could anybody explain why when using an if statement the "null" only is returned if it is in an array?

Comment: well filter is supposed to return true or false....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An item will be included in the resulting array if the value returned from the `filter` callback is truthy.

```
return val !== 0
```

will return `false` if `val` is 0, and `true` otherwise.

```
if(val !== 0) return val
```

will return `undefined` if the `val` is `0`, and will return the `val` otherwise. So, if the `val` is not `0`, but is still falsey (like `null`), it won't be included in the result.

But arrays are always truthy (no matter what values they contain), so

```
if(val !== 0) return [val]}
```

will *always* result in non-`0` values being included in the final array.

```js
console.log(Boolean(null));
console.log(Boolean([null]));
```

Comment: Oh, i misunderstood the behavior of filter. It's clear now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well [filter callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is supposed to return true or false.

You are not returning true or false. So it converts your item into a boolean.

So null is falsly an array would be truthy.